# Multiple aggregates in a SELECT statement in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this (Start and end time are epoch seconds)

| Job_ID | Job_Type | Start_Time | End_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 123 | A | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 456 | B | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 456 | B | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 789 | A | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 789 | A | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 012 | B | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |
| 012 | B | 1234567890 | 1234567890 |

What I would like to do is write a `SELECT` which first sums the total work time for each Job_ID, then it takes the average of total work time, grouped by Job_Type.

Output:

| Job_Type | Avg_Total_Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12345 |
| B | 12345 |

There are more than two work types - this is just an example.

To make matters more complex, I'm working in a JDBC environment and can't actually do things like create user variables and such.

I devised a way to do this by manually selecting each work type string literal and then using two sub selects to get total times and total jobs. The problem is that this isn't dynamic or scalable, and I'm not sure how to encompass this logic any other way.

I know I need to `GROUP BY` the Job_Type column, but I'm not sure how to get the times summed up before taking the average of them all.

My "Working" approach which is not scalable nor dynamic:

```
SELECT
'A' AS `Job_Type`,
-- Total Time worked for all Type A
ROUND(
    (
        SELECT SUM(End_time - Start_time) FROM MyTable
        WHERE Job_Type = 'A'
    )
    /
-- Divide by total Jobs of type A
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Job_ID) FROM MyTable
        WHERE Job_Type = 'A'
    )
) AS `Avg_Total_Time`

UNION

SELECT
'B' AS `Job_Type`,
ROUND(
    (
        SELECT SUM(End_time - Start_time) FROM MyTable
        WHERE Job_Type = 'B'
    )
    /
-- Divide by total Jobs of type B
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Job_ID) FROM MyTable
        WHERE Job_Type = 'B'
    )
) AS `Avg_Total_Time`
```

Comment: can a Job_ID have more than one Job_Type?  if yes, show some sample data and expected output that demonstates how you want that job's time accounted for

Comment: if no, seems like you are just asking for `select Job_Type, avg(s) from (select Job_Type,sum(End_Time-Start_Time) s from MyTable group by Job_ID,Job_Type) s`

Comment: @ysth A job can only have one job type The multiple rows are for multiple work times logged.

Comment: @ysth I'll run this query with my actual tables and see if it's what I need and let you know.

Comment: @ysth Looks like this is what I needed. Thanks for the comment. If you want to write up a response, I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: added an answer (and noticed I left off the final group by in my comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to sum the time for each job id in a subquery, and then you can calculate the average time for each job type in the outer query:

```
select Job_Type, avg(job_duration)
from (
    select Job_Type, sum(End_Time-Start_Time) job_duration
    from MyTable
    group by Job_ID, Job_Type
) job_durations
group by Job_Type
```